# Swapping UIViews for UIButtons in storyboard

Tags: xcode, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

I am guessing that this isn't possible. I spent about 2 hours laying out my views in autolayout. When I started coding, I realized that half of the views I laid out should actually be `UIButton`s. Is there anyway to just select a `UIView` and somehow change it to a `UIButton`? I tried typing in `UIButton`to the class field. But it didn't change all the attributes like as if I had dropped a `UIButton` on the storyboard.

Comment: Have you opened the storyboard as source?  It's possible, but rather tricky, to make global changes. Be sure to check the result carefully before commit.

Comment: That worked wonderfully. I just changed all the <view> tags to <button> tags.

Comment: @jbbenni that's a good answer! You should post it on answers, and have it be accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can open the Storyboard as source (right click on the Storyboard file and select `Open As` `Source Code`).  Then use `Find` Menu's `Find and Replace...` to make changes.  For example, change `<view>` to `<button>`.  `Save` the file.  After any desired text editing, right click on the Storyboard file again and `Open As` `Interface Builder - Storyboard` to restore the normal Storyboard view.

This is particularly useful when you want to change one color to another, or a to change a font name throughout a Storyboard.  Just be careful, Storyboards can be rather fragile as text.

Comment: It only took you 2.5 years. hahaha.

Comment: And I do this all the time now. Thanks @jbenni.